# Get all Jenkins credential bindings for all folders from the script console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have been using the following script for a year+ without issues:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials


Set<Credentials> allCredentials = new HashSet<Credentials>();


def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class
);


allCredentials.addAll(creds)


Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder.class).each{ f ->
 creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, f)
  allCredentials.addAll(creds)

}


for (c in allCredentials) {
  println(c.id)
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   description: " + c.description)
  }
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   username: " + c.username)
  }
  if (c.properties.password) {
    println("   password: " + c.password)
  }
  if (c.properties.passphrase) {
    println("   passphrase: " + c.passphrase)
  }
  if (c.properties.secret) {
    println("   secret: " + c.secret)
  }
  if (c.properties.privateKeySource) {
    println("   privateKey: " + c.getPrivateKey())
  }
  println("")
}
```

Now when I call it I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider#lookupCredentials.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.Class, class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [class java.lang.Class, interface hudson.model.Item]
    [class java.lang.Class, interface hudson.model.ItemGroup]
```

I think maybe a Jenkins update changed the `lookupCredentials` method.

I tried to explicitly case it to a `hudson.model.Item` but this results in the same error:

```
 folder = f as hudson.model.Item
 creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, folder)
```

## Edit

A more terse example snippet that causes the error:

```
def myFolder = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('my/folder')

def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, myFolder
)
```

Answer (score 1):

can reproduce your issue, try this

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials


Set<Credentials> allCredentials = new HashSet<Credentials>();


def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, hudson.security.ACL.SYSTEM
);


allCredentials.addAll(creds)


Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder.class).each{ f ->
 creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, f, hudson.security.ACL.SYSTEM)
  allCredentials.addAll(creds)

}


for (c in allCredentials) {
  println(c.id)
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   description: " + c.description)
  }
  if (c.properties.username) {
    println("   username: " + c.username)
  }
  if (c.properties.password) {
    println("   password: " + c.password)
  }
  if (c.properties.passphrase) {
    println("   passphrase: " + c.passphrase)
  }
  if (c.properties.secret) {
    println("   secret: " + c.secret)
  }
  if (c.properties.privateKeySource) {
    println("   privateKey: " + c.getPrivateKey())
  }
  println("")
}
```

or as item in another place also works for me

```
def myFolder = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('my/folder') 

def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class , myFolder as hudson.model.Item
)
```

ps add one more arg to call, will use another method

i see lot of deprecated methods https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/credentials/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/class-use/Credentials.html